# Schema index for words in a string

Tags: indexing, neo4j, lucene

I have a large amount of nodes which have the property `text` containing a string.

I want to find all nodes which text contains a given string (exact match). This can be done using the `CONTAINS` operator.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.text CONTAINS 'keyword'
RETURN n
```

Edit: I am looking for all nodes n where n.text contains the substring 'keyword'. E.g. `n.text = 'This is a keyword'`.

To speed up this I want to create an index for each word. Is this possible using the new [Schema Indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html)?

(Alternatively this could be done using a [legacy index](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html) and adding each node to this index but I would prefer using a schema index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Given that you are looking for an exact match you can use a schema index. Judging from your question you probably know this but to create the index you will need to assign your node a label and then create the index on that label.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :MyLabel(text)
```

Then at query time the cypher execution index will automatically use this index with the following query

```
MATCH (n:MyLabel { text : 'keyword' })
RETURN n
```

This will use the schema index to look up the node with label `MyLabel` and property `text` with value `keyword`. Note that this is an exact match of the complete value of the property.

To force Neo4j to use a particular index you can use [index hints](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-using.html#using-query-using-an-index-hint)

```
MATCH (n:MyLabel)
USING INDEX n:MyLabel(text)
WHERE n.text = 'keyword'
RETURN n
```

**EDIT**

On re-reading your question I am thinking you are not actually looking for a full exact match but actually wanting an exact match on the `keyword` parameter **within** the `text` field. If so, then...no, you cannot yet use schema indexes. Quoting [Use index with STARTS WITH](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-use-index-with-starts-with) in the Neo4j manual:

> The similar operators ENDS WITH and CONTAINS cannot currently be solved using indexes.

Comment: Thanks. Does CONTAINS work with a legacy index through?

Comment: Legacy indexes can be configured to be 'full-text' and so would not need the `CONTAINS` clause in theory. I have not used legacy indexing for some time however but in theory it would allow exact yet partial matching in an index lookup.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, a legacy index would accomplish exactly what you're looking to do. If you don't want to have to maintain the index for each node you create/delete/update, you can use auto indexing (http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/).

If you're looking to only use schema indexing, another approach would be to store each keyword as a separate node. Then you could use a schema index for finding relevant keyword nodes which then map to the node they exist on. Just a thought.